# Read HTML "windows.*" value on WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to read some variable from a website loaded in the webbrowser control on wp8.
I'm not really safe with HTML script.
So I'm not really sure if it is possible with "webBrowser.InvokeScript" or some other.

The site look like this:

```
<html class="no-js mobile">
<head><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new  Date().getTime()]);</script>
<title>test</title><meta content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    window.current_ip = '31.17.30.54';
  //]]>
</script>

<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    window.current_checkout = "{&quot;id&quot;:0,&quot;domestic&quot;:false,&quot;amount&quot;:0.0,&quot;updated_at&quot;:0,&quot;created_at&quot;:0}";
  //]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var _sift = _sift || [];
  _sift.push(['_setAccount', '637102']);
  _sift.push(['_setUserId', '1878617619']);
  _sift.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    function loadSift() {
      var sift = document.createElement('script');
      sift.type = 'text/javascript';
      sift.async = true;
      sift.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'dtlilztwypawv.cloudfront.net/s.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(sift, s);
    }
    if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', loadSift);
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', loadSift, false);
    }
  })();
</script>

</head>
```

I will be really happy if somebody can halp me!

edit -------------------

I'm think I'm one step nearer to the solution.
I run this code with success:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "newfunc_getmyvalue = function() { return 'hello'; }");
string s1 = (string)webBrowser.InvokeScript("newfunc_getmyvalue");
```

I now only need to know what "window.current_checkout = ..." exact do?
Is it really setting a variable? And how can I modify my 'hello' script to return this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a return value back from the invoked script, it must call windows.external.notify(), and your WebBrowser control must declare a ScriptNotify event handler to catch the data (in e.Value).

So this:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "window.external.notify(window.current_checkout);");
```

should emit the value from the web page, and

```
private void webBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    string response = e.Value;
    // do something wonderful with response
}
```

should capture it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HtmlAgilityPack` library to parse html, and then either use xpath or linq-to-xml to find the variables. 
Download the html with `webclient` and then parse with the library. There are other ways of downloading html as well.

Comment: WebClient might support invoking some events as well

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the response!
I try somethink like:
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "return window.current_project");

But the "return" command fails.
for example:
    InvokeScript("eval", "history.go()");
will work.

So I think I have to find the right command to return the value.